Options for dealing with an electrical box below new patio/sunroom floor that cannot be moved?
I have a junction box on the outside of my house. The top of the junction box is about 1" below the floor level of a concrete pad we will be pouring as the floor of a sunroom we are building. The sunroom contractor's electrician says that there isn't enough slack in the lines running to the box to allow it to be moved up. What are my alternative options?
I was thinking that we could leave a small hole in the slab around the junction box, and then cover it with some sort of metal plate, perhaps hinged.


What is this junction box for? That is, where do the wires come from/go to? Is there anything on the other side of the wall (e.g., a receptacle in the box), etc.?

I mean, you could build a handhole into your sunroom slab.

It has to be moved or you build a box with a door around it to keep it accessible.
The good thing about wires in conduit is that they can be pulled out and new wires pulled in.
If a cable goes inside the wall, then life gets harder.
